# Simple xpath question

Tags: xpath

I'm thinking this is a very simple xpath question .. I'm just not sure why my xpath isn't working.

Here's what my XML looks like

```
<A>
  <B>foo</B>
</A>

<C>
  <A>
    <B>foo</B>
  </A>
</C>
```

Now .. I want to grab all "A" elements which contain a "B" with contained text "foo".

Comment: what have you got so far that isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//A[B[text()='foo']]
```

- `//A` matches all `A`s
- `//A[B]` that have a `B` as a child
- `//A[B[text()='foo']]` which contains `foo` as text.

I suggest to read the [XPath tutorial at w3chools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath)

Comment: Needs to be the direct descendant.

Comment: Bingo!  You two nailed it.  I thought I'd tried everything .. I was at the point of calling it a bug in the xpath library .. but it was just incorrect xpath.  Thanks!

Comment: @FelixKling I am currently studying XPATH and facing much basic troubles. Which I couldn't put in SO,then down-vote must. :)) may I have some personal help for the same on email ? please